# Cypress test invoke("text") includes char \n. How can I strip it out?

Tags: cypress

I have a test that checks the contents of a div that has some text a new line and some more text, that can then be copied to the clipboard, My test is currently failing because of the `/n`.

> expected this is my first sentence\nthis is my second sentence

> to equal this is my first sentencethis is my second sentence

Is there a way I can strip that out?

```
 subject
  .getContainer()
  .should("be.visible")
  .invoke("text") 

  .then((text) => {
    cy.window()
      .its("navigator.clipboard")
      .invoke("readText") // The expect bit is coming from this invoke("readText")
      .should("equal", text);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A string replace with regex will do that

```js
.should("equal", text.replace(/\n/, ''))
```

In reverse

```js
.then((text) => {
  cy.window()
    .its("navigator.clipboard")
    .invoke("readText")
    .then(cbtext => cbtext.replace(/\n/, ''))
    .should("equal", text);
```

Comment: Yeah, but I need to do it on the text from the clipboard. `text` is what's in the container. I actually reversed the test eg instead of subject chain wrapping cy.window, cy.window is wrapping subject. it kinda works that way, but I'd rather do it the other way around.

Comment: To reverse the strip-out, chain another step after clipboard `readText`.